# SudzC generated code on Mac OSX app

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, sudzc

I'm new to xcode and SudzC. I'm trying to do an app for Mac OSX that can talk to a SOAP web service.

After some research I came across SudzC. It seems very nice but on the site I can´t find a direct xcode (not iPhone) objective-c option for the generated files. Can I convert the iPhone files to work on a Mac OSX app "easily"? Need some advice, thank you!

Comment: Objective-C code generated for handling SOAP web service should be platform independent (Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch). They use Foundation framework classes which is available for both iOS and MAC.

Comment: I will try that when I get home. I was trying that code on a iPhone app project because it was the option i chose on the SudzC site. But if it works on a MAC app would save me a lot of time... I know that there are common things but others are different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SudzC code on a Mac OSX app. 
I was having lots of warnings on my first try with a iPhone app, I didn't think it would be so easy to use that code on a Mac app...

Thanks 0x8badf00d, you're right. The code compiled just after a few minor modifications.